# Plutus Cohort 3: slot count why 11 and not 14

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program, slottime

I ran the auction exactly as shown. The slot count at the closing (after the additional wait) comes up to 14, not 11, as shown in the video. (if I add all the waits, the result is, indeed, 14). If the wait after Wallet3 bids is set to 8 (instead of 1), the final count is 11. Just puzzled! Thanks

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your playground steps that are being executed?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I believe in step 6 you're probably not setting the wait to *"wait until"* slot 11, but instead your waiting *"for"* 11 slots.

*(The reason for setting this to 11 was to wait until right after the deadline (spDeadline) which was set to slot 10)*

[image: Wait Until Button]